# Почему conio.h не подключился?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

У меня тут програма из учебника не запускается. Поможете?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float a = 5.5;
    float b = 1.5;
    float c = 3.3;
    textbackground(BLUE);
    textcollor(RED);
    clrscr();
    cprintf ("BLA BLA  ") ; 
    _getch();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, conio.h - это не часть стандарта. Раньше Borland и MS его поддерживали, но сейчас это отключено. Поэтому все старые примеры, в которых есть этот заголовок, надо поправить.

Предлагаю следующее: уберите строчки `#include <conio.h>` и `_getch();` из программы. И замените `cprintf` на `printf`. Также нет простого способа установить цвет, поэтому уберём пока       `textbackground` и `textcolor`. После этого она должна заработать. Если этого хватает, то хорошо.

Если же надо, чтобы консоль не закрывалась сразу, то надо чуть-чуть дополнить программу. Это можно сделать, например, добавив вызов следующей функции:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

void PressEnterToContinue()
{
  std::cout << "Press ENTER to continue... " << flush;
  std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits <std::streamsize> ::max(), '\n' );
}
```

Тогда программа будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

void PressEnterToContinue()
{
  std::cout << "Press ENTER to continue... " << flush;
  std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits <std::streamsize> ::max(), '\n' );
}

int main()
{
  float a = 5.5;
  float b = 1.5;
  float c = 3.3;
  printf ("BLA BLA  "); 
  PressEnterToContinue();
}
```

Comment: `std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits <std::streamsize> ::max(), '\n' );` — ох, #крестопроблемы...

Comment: @Viktor кстати, у вас в `textcollor` опечатка - должно быть `textcolor`

Answer (score 2):

Вы бы при указании, что что-то не так, четко писали, что именно не так. Вы же не звоните доктору по телефону "мне плохо" и ждете, что вам помогут? Не говоря о том, что именно болит, не делая анализов и т.д.?

По конкретной программе. Она **не компилируется**, а не **не запускается**.
Нестандартность `conio.h` приводит к тому, что каждый компилятор поддерживает то, что хочет :), и всех этих функций, которые вы пытаетесь использовать, в VC++2015 просто нет. Хотя сам `conio.h` и есть...

Программу или надо переписывать с привлечением консольного API Windows (вряд ли это вам нужно...), либо брать что-то типа старого доброго Borland C++ 3.1 под DOS :) и работать с ним.

Comment: Спасибо буду переписывать